# Why didn't my laminated dough rise?

Tags: dough, rising

[image]I'm trying to make croissants for the first time and my dough is not rising in between folds.  I don't know whether to just keep going or if it's trash and I should start over?

Comment: I'm guessing it will help out a lot if you explain the method you've followed more exactly and/or post the recipe you're using and where you are at in the steps.

Comment: There are two main types of croissant recipes and - like so often - a few typical pitfalls, so please follow @Catija's advice and post the recipe.

Comment: Well, I just kept going and they turned out okay.  I'm going to experiment with other recipes and get better.  I was going to show you a picture @Catija & Stephie but I couldn't figure out how to do that either!  :)  thank you!

Comment: @DiBar , if you want to add a picture click "edit" on you own post. Position the cursor in the text field where you want the picture to go. Over the text field there are a few formatting icons, one of them either a "picture frame" or a "camera" (depending on browser vs. app version). Click on this and a pop-up window will guide you through the process. If the app doesn't work, try opening it in your browser, there is even a "link" under each post to do so. You might have to login in your browser again.

Answer (score 3):

Laminated or "roll-in" doughs don't rise in the traditional sense. Between folds rising is very minimal. You won't see a true rise until you proof your croissants.